# c# Remove elements from List containing string

Tags: c#, list

I have a List with 100k elements. I want to remove all elements from list that 
contain one of the strings from another List. I use RemoveAll which is quite slow, so wondering if there is a better solution.

```
public static void RemoveElements(List<string> input, List<string> items)
{
   foreach(var item in items)
   {
       input.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains(item));
   }
}
```

Comment: RemoveAll is already fastest option, so the only thing you can do is to not call it multiple times with "string contains in array" check as shown in duplicate.